# Ways to bind Enums to WPF controls like Combobox, TabHeader etc

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, enums

In my program (MVVM WPF) there are lot of Enumerations, I am binding the enums to my controls in the view.

There are lot of ways to do it.

1) To bind to ComboBoxEdit(Devexpress Control). I am using ObjectDataProvider.

and then this

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomeEnumValues}>
```

This works fine but in TabControl header it doesn't.

2) So, I thought of using IValueConverter that didnt worked either.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
    CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (!(value is Model.MyEnum))
    {
        return null;
    }

    Model.MyEnum me = (Model.MyEnum)value;
    return me.GetHashCode();
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return null;
}
```

on XAML:

```
<local:DataConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>

<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedFeeType, 
      Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"/>
```

3) The third way of doing this is to make a behavior dependency property

Something like this

```
public class ComboBoxEnumerationExtension : ComboBox
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedEnumerationProperty =  
          DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedEnumeration", typeof(object), 
          typeof(ComboBoxEnumerationExtension));

        public object SelectedEnumeration
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedEnumerationProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedEnumerationProperty, value); }
        }
```

I want to know what is the best way to handle enumerations and binding to it. Right now I am not able to bind tabheader to the enums.

Comment: What's the goal exactly? Just bind the tab header labels to the enum values?

Comment: Yes ans also is there a common way to get the values of enum that can be used to bind to any control. like using ObjectDataProvied or using Converters.

Comment: Well, I think #2 should work -- but don't you need a two-way binding, and implement the "ConvertBack" method?

Comment: Can you share the XAML for your TabControl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a nicer way of doing it:

On your model, put this Property:

```
public IEnumerable<string> EnumCol { get; set; }
```

(Feel free to change the name to whatever suits you, but just remember to change it everywhere)

In the constructor have this (or even better, put it in an initialization method):

```
var enum_names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(YourEnumTypeHere));
EnumCol = enum_names ;
```

This will take all the names from your `YourEnumTypeHere` and have them on the property you'll be binding to in your xaml like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding EnumCol}"></ListBox>
```

Now, obviously, it doesn't have to be a ListBox, but now you're simply binding to a collection of strings, and your problem should be solved.